# resignFirstResponder does not dismiss keyboard even though code is ran

Tags: ios7, resignfirstresponder

This line of code is ran when my email textField editingDidEnd. The NSLog runs so I know the function is ran but the keyboard still does not go away. Ive connected the textBox as a delegate. Ive made sure the connections in storyboard are there. It still wont change. Help. Thanks.

```
- (IBAction)emailDone2:(id)sender
{
    [_email resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"emailDone2");
}
```

EDIT ******** I changed the code as instructed and this still does nothing. Nothing has changed.

```
- (IBAction)emailDone2:(id)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:TRUE];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that who you think is first responder and who *is* first responder may not be the same. Fortunately, there's already a method that will fix this up. Try using

```
[topView endEditing:YES];
```

where topView is the topmost view. endEditing will recurse through the subviews, find the one that is first responder, and tell it to resign first responder. This is much simpler than tracking which subview has it.

Found this in [keyboard not responding to resignFirstResponder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051402/keyboard-not-responding-to-resignfirstresponder), linked in the sidebar to this question.

Comment: I'm not 100% on what topView is and where this should go in my program. My viewController has text boxes and when the user finishes in one and touches the screen anywhere else I want the keyboard to go away.

Comment: Try sending it to your main view controller; it should find the one with first responder for you and tell it to send the keyboard away.

Answer (score 0):

The return value of textViewShouldEndEditing should be true for the resignFirstResponder to dismiss